# Problem making a post request in React and Express with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

im trying to use nodemailer in a express/reactjs stack but im having some problems.

In the reactjs component i have:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/form", {
        firstName: "Name",
        lastName: "Lname"
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

And then in the server side:

```
app.post("api/form", (req, res) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "user",
      pass: "pass"
    }
  });

  let mailOptions = {
    from: "test@test.com",
    to: "mail@ethereal.email",
    replyTo: "test@test.com",
    subject: "New msg",
    text: "Hi",
    html: "<p>Just an email</p>"
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("message sent: ", info.msg);
  });
});
```

the server running

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server in port: ${port}`));
```

The error i have in te console is

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/form 404 (Not Found)
```

and the console error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting a 404 status code is because you forgot the slash before `api/form`. It should be `app.post('/api/form')`.

Also by the way you didn't return a response. That will cause a response timeout after a request is made which your code is waiting for.

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/api/form", {
    firstName: "Name",
    lastName: "Lname"
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // NO RESPONSE IS COMING
  })
```